# Entity Framework - MVC 3 Timeout Issue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem with my site.  I made a small change to a stored procedure.  I've tested the stored procedure in SSMS and then updated my Entity Framework to return the two new rows I added.

But now when I load the page that includes the Stored Procedure the page times out.  Which I thought was really weird.  So I ran a SQL Server Profiler on my SQL Server and was really surprised.

Run from MVC 3 via Entry Framework exec [dbo].[zzz] @LogDate='2012-11-13 00:00:00',@UserID=1,@LocationID=76,@CategoryID=NULL - CPU 59469 - Reads 101693134- Duration - 60091

Copy the execute statement from the Profiler and run it directly in SSMS and I get this result:

Run from SSMS exec [dbo].[zzz] @LogDate='2012-11-13 00:00:00',@UserID=1,@LocationID=76,@CategoryID=NULL - CPU 47 - Reads 60185 - Duration - 151

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting such radically different results from the same SP?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...  Figured it out.  Entity Framework, wasn't really passing a null for the last value.  When I added the following line to the Stored Procedure, it started to work on the website:

```
IF(@CategoryID = '')
    SET @CategoryID = NULL
```

Not sure why the Profiler was showing a NULL, when the SP was receiving it as a empty string.  In the code I was passing it as a null.

```
var dle = context.dEGet(ld,userID,lastLocationID,null).ToList();
```

Comment: You could also pass it as `DBNull.Value` to get NULL in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks dombenoit, I'll give that a try too.